# Magento 2 : Is there any way to showing billing and shipping address in formatted view?

Tags: magento2

i just need to show billing and shipping address in formatted view ?
Any idea please share

Comment: Its Solved. using below class
\Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Address\Renderer $addressRenderer

Answer (score 0):

Following works for me.

```
//.... in __construct()
\Magento\Customer\Api\AddressRepositoryInterface $addressRepository,
\Magento\Customer\Model\Address\Config $addressConfig,
\Magento\Customer\Model\Address\Mapper $addressMapper,    

$address = ....; //get address
$renderer = $this->_addressConfig->getFormatByCode('oneline')->getRenderer();
$addressObject = $this->addressRepository->getById($address->getId());
echo $renderer->renderArray($this->addressMapper->toFlatArray($addressObject));
```

You can edit formats in Admin > STORES > Configuration > CUSTOMERS > Customer Configuration > Address Templates. Defaults magento templates are:

- text
- oneline
- html
- pdf